# Iterate Dictionary with dictionary data and add it to an array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, iphone, swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary with multiple dictionary data :

```
{
    1455201094707 =     {
    };
    1455201116404 =     {
    }: 
    1455201287530 =     {
    };
}
```

I have to add all these dictionaries to an array in swift. 
How to iterate dictionary as :

```
for let tempDict in dataDictionary
{
     self.tempArray.addObject(tempDict)
}
```

> Error "let pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable
>   context"

```
for tempDict in dataDictionary as! NSMutableDictionary
{
     self.tempArray.addObject(tempDict)
}
```

> Error : Argument type element(aka(key:AnyObject, value:AnyObject))
>   argument type does not conform to expected type anyobject

```
for tempDict in dataDictionary as! NSMutableDictionary
{
     self.tempArray.addObject(tempDict as! AnyObject)
}
```

> Error: Could not cast value of type '(Swift.AnyObject,
>   Swift.AnyObject)' (0x1209dee18) to 'Swift.AnyObject' (0x11d57d018).

```
for tempDict in dataDictionary
{
     self.tempArray.addObject(tempDict)
}
```

> Error: Value of Type AnyObject has no member generator

**Edit**

I want the final array as :

```
(
  {
    1455201094707 =     {
    };
  }
  {
     1455201116404 =     {
     }:
  } 
)
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Any help will be appreciated.....

I have used code :

```
var tempArray:[NSDictionary] = []

    for (key, value) in tempDict {
        tempArray.append([key : value])
    }
```

> Error: value of type AnyObject does not conform to expected dictionary key type NSCopying

code :

```
let tempArray = tempDict.map({ [$0.0 : $0.1] })
```

> Error : type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, when you use

```
for let tempDict in dataDictionary {
     self.tempArray.addObject(tempDict)
}
```

Swift gives you tuple like (key, value) in tempDict.

So you should iterate like this

```
for (key, value) in sourceDict {
     tempArray.append(value)
}
```

**Note:** I used here native swift structures, and my advise - to use them as often as possible (instead of ObjC ones)

Or you can use map-function on dictionary.

```
let array = sourceDict.map({ $0.1 })
```

**Edit.** For

```
(
  {
    1455201094707 =     {
    };
  }
  {
     1455201116404 =     {
     }:
  } 
)
```

use

```
for (key, value) in sourceDict {
     tempArray.append([key : value])
}
```

or

```
let array = dict.map({ [$0.0 : $0.1] })
```

**Note.** if you use NSDictionary you should cast it to swift Dictionary

```
if let dict = dict as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let array = dict.map({ [$0.0 : $0.1] })
    print(array)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the question, can you tell me how to do that..??

Comment: I have used code : 

var tempArray:[NSDictionary] = []
        
        for (key, value) in tempDict {
            tempArray.append([key : value])
        }


Error: value of type anyobject does not conform to expected dictionary key type nscopying

Comment: code : let array = dict.map({ [$0.0 : $0.1] }) gives error : type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Again, I used native swift types. You should better use them everywhere or cast to them.

Comment: Thanks @Anton, It is showing an issue " Cast from NSMutableDictionary to unrelated type [string:anyobject] always fails" but output is correct. One more thing , how to add this array to NSmutableArray , to show data in tableView ?

Comment: @amit0226 It's magic of swift. For some reason it allows to cast from NSDictionary to Dictionary<Stirng, AnyObject>, but not from NSMutableDictionary. Maybe you should first cast from NSMutableDictionary to NSDictionary (or use copy() function) and then cast to swift Dictionary

Comment: @amit0226, About arrays: you can use result array as is, or just cast it to ObjC NSArray. Btw better not to use mutable variants of collections if you don't need to actually mutate them

Comment: Thank you @Anton once again. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2):

1. Get all keys from the dictionary, for this `NSDictionary` has property `allKeys`.
2. Loop all keys, and add object for the key to the array.
3. Before the all steps above, read [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/)!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the question, can you tell me how to do that..??