# How do i parse JSON, sort it in an array. Pull out the data and populate to a tableview?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

i am trying to parse JSON into an array. Sort it according the highest appointment made. And then use that new array to populate it on leaderboard tableview.

I am using SwiftJson
Stuck on sorting into array

Would need to populate Name and the rest of the values in tableview in descending order.

Here are my snippets.

```
        let jsonUrl = URL(string: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: jsonUrl!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let jsonResult : JSON = JSON(data)
            print(jsonResult)


    } .resume()
```

Here are the output

```
{
  "Activities" : {
    "AHiHr9bzGXcN7pxvR68wulD9zqE3" : {
      "Case Closed" : "2",
      "Name" : "Tim Mac",
      "Appointment Made" : "2",
      "Prospects Met" : "2",
      "Policy Servicing" : "2"
    },
    "gDKBlbeMsiUUFaASOLn6eOdCIrJ3" : {
      "Case Closed" : "1",
      "Name" : "Jane Simpson",
      "Appointment Made" : "1",
      "Prospects Met" : "1",
      "Policy Servicing" : "1"
    },
    "W8uWoLf9qRX4a9BgXjLw5VZXjFu1" : {
      "Case Closed" : "3",
      "Name" : "John Doe",
      "Appointment Made" : "4",
      "Prospects Met" : "3",
      "Policy Servicing" : "2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `JSONSerialization` or use external library like `SwiftyJSON`

Comment: "How do i parse JSON, sort it in an array. Pull out the data and populate to a tableview?" That's 3 different questions, and each have been already asked on SO and have answers. Also `JSON = JSON(data)` what's that code? You are already parsing, no ?

Comment: above one is not array of dictionaries it is dictionaries of dictionary

Comment: Please check this it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431754/iterate-dictionary-with-dictionary-data-and-add-it-to-an-array-in-swift

Comment: Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswifty-json%5D+parse), this kind of question is one of the top ten questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all values as Array of Dictionary and Sort it Like :

```
  guard let Activities = jsonResult?["Activities"] as? [String:AnyObject] else {
            return
        }

        var values = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]()

        for (_, value) in Activities {
            values.append(value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
        }


        let sorted =   values.sorted { (dic1, dic2) -> Bool in

            Int(dic1["Appointment Made"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0 > Int(dic2["Appointment Made"] as? String ?? "") ?? 0

        }

        print(sorted)
```

// model your data

```
 for item in sorted {

            let model = Model.init(jsonData: item)

            // use model
        }
```

// your model

```
class Model: NSObject {

    var caseClosed :Int?
    var name :String?
    var appointmentMade :Int?
    var prospectsMet :Int?
    var policyServicing :Int?



    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(jsonData : [String:AnyObject]) {

        //  map data to object

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi bro! Thank for the help. I am getting close to the answer already. With a bit of modification to the answer you provided i was able to get this output

[["Appointment Made": 4, "Prospects Met": 3, "Policy Servicing": 2, "Name": John Doe, "Case Closed": 3], ["Appointment Made": 2, "Prospects Met": 2, "Policy Servicing": 2, "Name": Tim Mac, "Case Closed": 2], ["Appointment Made": 1, "Prospects Met": 1, "Policy Servicing": 1, "Name": Jane Simpson, "Case Closed": 1]]

Comment: How do i assign them to an data model array so i can populate them. For a single data model i am able to populate. But for an array of it i do not know. =( sorry i am very noob.

Comment: Create. Model with this attribute and pass sorted array for this model are you need it

Comment: The code in the question is clearly Swift 3. The type of a JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`

Comment: you can use Any instead Anybject will not cause any problem

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish You *can* do many things. All JSON types in Swift 3 are value types (no objects) so `Any` is the appropriate type.

Comment: Thank you Darwish and Vadian for all your help. I have managed to solve the issue. Much appreciated! Bless you guys, Cheer~

Answer (score -1):

Use JsonSerialisation jsonObjectWithData to convert jSon response to NSArray object. And run a for loop, access every element in array as NSDictionary and compare their values for highest appointment.

To know more about accessing values from NSDictionary, [apple docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary)

To know more about working with json in swift, [apple docs reference](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37).

Answer (score -1):

I  have tried this sorting:

```
let activitiesDict = jsonData?["Activities"] as? [String:Any]

let activitiesArray = activitiesDict.map({ [$0.0 : $0.1] })

let sortedActivitiesArray = self.activitiesArray.sorted {
            (Int((($0 as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["Appointment Made"] as? String)!))! > (Int((($1 as! Dictionary<String, Any>)["Appointment Made"] as? String)!))!      
        }
print(sortedActivitiesArray)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The code in the question is clearly Swift 3. The type of a JSON dictionary in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`. And don't suggest `NSMutable...` collection types in Swift.

Comment: @vadian : I have changed the format. I added the code which I used in my project to give an idea.