# Swift 3: Sort Ordered List of Objects by Property

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, swift3

In Swift 3 I define my array as:

```
var filteredObjects = [Int: CustomObject]()
```

then I populate array with data:

```
filteredObjects[filteredObjects.count] = CustomObject
```

Now I want to sort array by (1) property "title" of `CustomObject` which is a `String` and (2) a float property "distance" of `CustomObject`.

When I try:

```
filteredObjects.sort({ $0.distance < $1.distance })
```

it produces error **Value of tuple type (key:Int, value:CustomObject) has no member distance**

I suspect I cannot use `sort` method like this but I cannot find the solution.

Comment: Your *array* is actually a dictionary. A dictionary is unordered by definition.

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431754/iterate-dictionary-with-dictionary-data-and-add-it-to-an-array-in-swift . if it helps in your scenario.

Comment: `let sortedTuples = filteredObjects.sorted{ $0.value.distance < $1.value.distance }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift 3: 
While using sort in filteredObjects i.e dictionary $0 will give you a single object from filteredObjects which will be of tuple type "**((key: Int, value: CustomObject), (key: Int, value: CustomObject))**". $0.distance will actually try to find distance property in the tuple which isn't available in the result tuple, so you are getting error **Value of tuple type (key:Int, value:CustomObject) has no member distance**

What you can do is

```
let resultDictionary = filteredObjects.sorted() { 
  $0.0.value.distance < $0.1.value.distance 
}
```

$0.0.value is of type CustomObject which have property distance according to which you want to sort the result.

Special thanks to @Leo Dabus.

Comment: Btw by using the parentheses you need to add the by: keyword

Comment: And you can’t use sort. Dictionary is an unordered collection

Comment: I have already up voted your comment. I tried to explain why @Vad is getting that error.

Comment: again by using the parentheses you need to add the `by:` keyword `.sorted(by: { ... })` or remove the parentheses `.sorted { ... }`