# JSON with variable dates in SwiftyJson for iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I want to parse a json with variable keys. Here is the example:

```
"Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-09-14": {
            "1. open": "113.3600",
            "2. high": "113.7300",
            "3. low": "112.4400",
            "4. close": "113.3700",
            "5. adjusted close": "113.3700",
            "6. volume": "19122349",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2018-09-13": {
            "1. open": "112.1200",
            "2. high": "113.7250",
            "3. low": "112.1200",
            "4. close": "112.9100",
            "5. adjusted close": "112.9100",
            "6. volume": "26055620",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2018-09-12": {
            "1. open": "111.4300",
            "2. high": "111.8500",
            "3. low": "110.5100",
            "4. close": "111.7100",
            "5. adjusted close": "111.7100",
            "6. volume": "18891064",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        }
        ...
    }
```

Using SwiftyJSON i know how to convert a JSON with static keys. But i am not aware of any way to take date (2018-09-13 etc) as a Data Bean and create an Array of dates. What is the best way to handle this scenario?

The code i use for parsing the static keys in SwiftJSON is:

```
func get<T>(url: String, queryParams: Parameters!, onComplete: @escaping (T?, Error?) -> ()) where T : Codable {
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: queryParams, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: self.headers!).responseString {
            response in
            print("URL: \(url)")

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
                if (statusCode == Constant.httpSuccessCode){
                    print("Value: \(value)")
                    let json: String = JSON(value).string!
                    let jsonObj : T! = StringManager.decode(stringRepresentation: json)
                    onComplete(jsonObj, nil)
                }else if(statusCode == Constant.httpInternalServerErrorCode){
                   //Error handling
                }else if(statusCode == Constant.httpForbiddenCode || statusCode == Constant.httpUnAuthorizedCode){
                   //error handling
                }else {
                   //error handling
                }

            case .failure(let error):
               //error handling
            }
            //response is the json.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431754/iterate-dictionary-with-dictionary-data-and-add-it-to-an-array-in-swift . May be it will help what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think you can use Swift Json Serialization. After Swift 4 , you dont need to Swifty or something like that.

Comment: @Usama Aftab any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Ali Ihsan and Sahil, thanks for your comments. I understood it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json's root is a JsonObject i.e. Key and Value
Date is the key and value is again a JsonObject. So it can be handled like

**Code**

```
import SwiftyJSON
class Test{

    let s = """

    {"Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2018-09-14": {
            "1. open": "113.3600",
            "2. high": "113.7300",
            "3. low": "112.4400",
            "4. close": "113.3700",
            "5. adjusted close": "113.3700",
            "6. volume": "19122349",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2018-09-13": {
            "1. open": "112.1200",
            "2. high": "113.7250",
            "3. low": "112.1200",
            "4. close": "112.9100",
            "5. adjusted close": "112.9100",
            "6. volume": "26055620",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        },
        "2018-09-12": {
            "1. open": "111.4300",
            "2. high": "111.8500",
            "3. low": "110.5100",
            "4. close": "111.7100",
            "5. adjusted close": "111.7100",
            "6. volume": "18891064",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0000"
        }
    }
    }
    """
    func parseJSON(){

        let j = JSON(parseJSON: s)
        let timeSeries = j["Time Series (Daily)"]
        for (key,json) in timeSeries{
            print("\(key):")
            json.forEach({
            print("\($0) : \($1)")
        })
        }

    }

}
```

**output**

```
   2018-09-14:
1. open : 113.3600
4. close : 113.3700
8. split coefficient : 1.0000
5. adjusted close : 113.3700
3. low : 112.4400
7. dividend amount : 0.0000
2. high : 113.7300
6. volume : 19122349
2018-09-12:
1. open : 111.4300
4. close : 111.7100
8. split coefficient : 1.0000
5. adjusted close : 111.7100
3. low : 110.5100
7. dividend amount : 0.0000
2. high : 111.8500
6. volume : 18891064
2018-09-13:
1. open : 112.1200
4. close : 112.9100
8. split coefficient : 1.0000
5. adjusted close : 112.9100
3. low : 112.1200
7. dividend amount : 0.0000
2. high : 113.7250
6. volume : 26055620
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks Sahil. The logic makes complete sense so i am accepting your answer. I guess, i was looking for an auto serialization but since json does not have static keys, you can't really serialize it.